# Why doesn't Linux detect my windows OS?

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint

I wanted to install Linux Mint alongside Windows 10 (with Windows 10 already installed); but the moment I was going through installation process, I got stuck at the command that I have to erase my data on my internal HDD, because Linux can't detect any OS in it.

These are several things I tried before:

- HDD partition on my internal HDD into unallocated amount.
- Trying to make it as GPT system other than MBR, using `diskpart`, but still afraid to proceed it because, I have read that I have to clean up the disk 0 (as the only disk that is shown in "diskpart command"), then convert it to GPT.
- Browsing other things on youtube and still have no idea.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can choose "Something else" as Installation type and manually create the partitions for linux mint without touching windows partitions.

Hopefully this will help http://www.bytelinux.com/install-linux-mint-17-1-dual-boot-windows-10-uefi-systems/

Comment: The thing is that i gone through "something else" option, then it only showed up my only internal HDD without any partition in it, when i looked at my friend's process he got several HDD partition from his internal one. so it asked me to erase my entire space (1TB). that was weird. Cause i already did some partitions in my windows as i said earlier. but anyway let me know if you have an idea. Thanks bro.